# Recursive listing of all files matching a certain filetype in Groovy

Tags: recursion, groovy, matching

I am trying to recursively list all files that match a particular file type in Groovy. [This example](http://groovy-almanac.org/list-files-recursivly/) almost does it. However, it does not list the files in the root folder. Is there a way to modify this to list files in the root folder? Or, is there a different way to do it?

Answer (score 109, accepted):

This should solve your problem:

```
import static groovy.io.FileType.FILES

new File('.').eachFileRecurse(FILES) {
    if(it.name.endsWith('.groovy')) {
        println it
    }
}
```

`eachFileRecurse` takes an enum FileType that specifies that you are only interested in files. The rest of the problem is easily solved by filtering on the name of the file. Might be worth mentioning that `eachFileRecurse` normally recurses over both files and folders while `eachDirRecurse` only finds folders.

Answer (score 27):

groovy version 2.4.7 :

```
new File(pathToFolder).traverse(type: groovy.io.FileType.FILES) { it ->
    println it
}
```

you can also add filter like

```
new File(parentPath).traverse(type: groovy.io.FileType.FILES, nameFilter: ~/patternRegex/) { it ->
    println it
}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
// Define closure
def result

findTxtFileClos = {

        it.eachDir(findTxtFileClos);
        it.eachFileMatch(~/.*.txt/) {file ->
                result += "${file.absolutePath}\n"
        }
    }

// Apply closure
findTxtFileClos(new File("."))

println result
```

Comment: Your snippet will find the same file several times. To make it work you will have to use eachDirRecurse instead and for each dir use dir.eachFileMatch to find the files in the directory. Check my solution for another way to solve the problem.

Answer (score 4):

replace `eachDirRecurse` by `eachFileRecurse` and it should work.