# Attempting to access file system from jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to access the file system from a Jenkinsfile using groovy. I'm following the suggestion in this SO thread: 
[Recursive listing of all files matching a certain filetype in Groovy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3662144)

I've already given access to

```
new java.io.File java.lang.String
staticField groovy.io.FileType FILES
```

under Script Approvals.

However this line is failing without an error message:

```
new File('.').eachFileRecurse(FILES) {
```

Here's the broader code block in question:

```
stage("Install") {
  print "here a"
  new File('.').eachFileRecurse(FILES) {
    print "here c"
    if(it.name.endsWith(".sh")) {
      print "here d"
      println it
    }
  }
  print "here b"
```

Here's the console output from that section:

```
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Install)
[Pipeline] echo
here a
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] echo
Email Recipients: opike99@gmail.com, opike@yahoo.com
[Pipeline] emailext
messageContentType = text/html; charset=UTF-8
Adding recipients from project recipient list
Adding recipients from trigger recipient list
Setting In-Reply-To since last build was not successful
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better use the [`findFiles`](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#code-findfiles-code-find-files-in-the-workspace) step, instead of the Java API to read files. This is whitelisted by script security.

`each` loops don't work in pipeline because of Jenkins' CPS. Instead (if you really prefer it over good old `for` loops), wrap it in a method annotated with [`@NonCPS`](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-cps-plugin/blob/master/README.md#technical-design).