# How do i list a set of files in groovy?

Tags: groovy

If I'm trying to do a simple search of all files ending in a certain file format such as:

```
ls *.doc
```

How do I do this using groovy?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Recursive listing of all files matching a certain filetype in Groovy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3662144/recursive-listing-of-all-files-matching-a-certain-filetype-in-groovy)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get list of files matching a target name, use the *eachFileMatch* method. To find files ending with .doc use the pattern /.*\.doc/.

```
def currentFile = new File('.')
currentDir.eachFileMatch(FileType.FILES, ~/.*\.doc/) { f ->
 println(f.name)
}
```